# In Windows' Run command line, how to open "My computer"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

if I do run (Winkey + R) and type "C:\", explorer shows up in "C:\".

I'd like to know how to do the same for the My Computer folder in Windows Vista / 7.

Comment: I've found this when I was searching run prompt history. Try ' file: ' without quotes. :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could just press WIN+E and skip the run prompt all together.

Comment: I'd agree with this one

Comment: I was just about to say this... then I realized you beat me to it by 3 years!

Comment: This don't answer the question. The question ask "from cmd line".

Comment: Nope, it gives an alternative solution that the OP may not have known about, and since it is the accepted answer and the answer with the must up votes I would conclude the OP and at least 41 others found it helpful.

Answer (score 48):

**The easiest way is to type `shell:mycomputerfolder` or Win+E**

[Here is a list of other locations.](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)

Comment: Note that running command  `shell:mycomputerfolder` will not start `mycomputerfolder` if it's already open. On the other hand pressing `win+e` will open `mycomputerfolder` as many times as you press it.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 1809. I saw that, in a command prompt, `start shell:mycomputerfolder` raises an *existing* File Explorer window showing "This PC" as @IGRACH suggested. But both `explorer shell:mycomputerfolder` and `start explorer shell:mycomputerfolder` open a new window even if "This PC" is already open.

Answer (score 30):

Try :

```
explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

Comment: It'd be useful to know how you worked that one out

Comment: @barlop: Google is my friend.

Comment: @harrymc if you found it via google then the exact link would've been useful in your answer. But i'll have a look

Comment: @harrymc you may have hit on something that is generically useful.. in launching anything obscure. And all one needs is the GUID.. just have to find the GUID somehow. Only thing is it's a bit inefficient, as it is.

Comment: @barlop: There are hundreds of class-names describing places, as Explorer is the main user interface for Windows. The one above comes from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` (look at the sub-keys). For the grand-daddy of them all, use Explorer to create a folder called `ControlPanel.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`, then look inside.

Comment: there anyway to disable something like this? like, you know something someone might do to ruin a computer and prevent competent people from retrieving data before a wipe?

Comment: @Jasen: I don't believe this can be disabled, except maybe by destroying the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT entries in the registry, which might in turn cause an unknown number of problems. Or to disable Explorer except for the desktop (which I don't know how to).

Comment: @harrymc that could be done by rewriting explorer, and replacing it on a reboot. but itd take an awful lot of space, and incredible user stupidity to get through. hmmm. im very glad i read this. and yeah destroying that part of the registry would basically make the system a brick.

Comment: @Jasen: I didn't mean all of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, just the entries for these user-interfaces. But that would disable them for *everybody*.

Comment: @harrymc Ah yeah, it would. that's the best and worst thing about windows registry. it does exactly what you tell it to.

Comment: @harrymc  I just tried, using explorer, in windows xp, to create a folder ControlPanel.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}  And it won't open. It says windows cannot open this file.

Comment: You can just use **::CLSID** part. That is **::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}**

Comment: oh so wonderfull thanks!! and all the comments good as well!!

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Because it allows you to create a desktop shortcut to "My Computer" on Windows 10.

Answer (score 19):

The closest I can think of is typing the below into the run dialog;

```
...
```

But I believe that only brings up your home folder.

Comment: Yes, this only brings up the user's home folder.

Comment: It brings up "my computer"  for me! Where did you hear of that one?  try adding more dots if it doesn't work. e.g. start run (dot) <ENTER> gets to %userprofile%, then .. would go up one level, and ... up 2 levels which should be c:\ but if for some reason it wasn't (why?!) then you could add more dots  (adding to what I just wrote) it brings up "my computer" in XP. I can't comment on windows vista

Comment: `.` always means the current directory, and `..` its parent. Three or more dots has no special meaning; however, since Windows API normally strips off the trailing dots from a filename (`foo.bar.` automatically becomes `foo.bar`), some programs treat `...` the same way as `..`, and others strip off _all_ dots resulting in empty path.

Comment: @grawity  +1 seems about right- I see "cd ..." in cmd is just nothing  But start run ...  Does start "my computer" in xp. Whereas start run ..  does not.  start run ..\..\..\..\   just goes to C:\      (which is understandable) and doesn't start "my computer". So I guess perhaps ... is just a start run thing. I'd not seen ... listed in the few start run shortcut lists i've seen.

Comment: In XP it opens My Computer but in Win7 it opens my home folder.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Interesting.

Comment: Actually, I believe Windows special-cases any sequence of N>2 `.` to mean "N minus 1 levels up". So `..` means "one level up", `...` means "two levels up", `....` means "three levels up", and so on, *from the current working directory*. Don't know if this is actually documented somewhere, though, so might not be something you want to rely on.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way:

- Write: `explorer =` and *My Computer* window will pop up
- Write: `explorer c:`  and the C drive window will open.

This is working fine on Windows 7.

Comment: `explorer =` seriously?? I love it haha

Comment: Works on my Windows 10 1809. Opens "This PC". Prepend with "start" also does the same thing: start explorer =

Answer (score 10):

This one

`explorer /root,`

Yes, the comma is important

Comment: That one is just cool.

Comment: Fancy, but doesn't work on Windows Vista.

Comment: This is A Thing of Beauty. For a second you can feel like a boss :D

Answer (score 3):

I wanted this too, but I've just gotten in the habit of opening the C: drive through the Run dialog then pressing backspace to go up a folder into My Computer.

It's not really the "right" answer but it gets me there in just one additional keystroke so I'm happy with it. Much better than memorizing any GUIDs, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
runas /noprofile /user:domain\username explorer
```

It works for all other command line options as far as I know.

Comment: ... starts Explorer with "Libraries" open, not "My Computer" under Windows 7.