# 'My Computer' keyboard shortcut without Windows key

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to launch My Computer from the keyboard when the keyboard does not have a Windows key?

Remapping keys etc. or registry tweaks will not be useful in my scenario as I have to do this on lots of computers. I'm renaming computers after imaging, using an image that has had the My Computer icon removed.

Comment: Doesn't your image ask for a computer name after it boots for the first time? If not, how was the image made? (usually that is with a clean install, windows updates, some programs and then sysprep with a flag to regenerate that computers **unique** key and network name).

Comment: No, it doesn't ask. This isn't a normal network deployment scenario, they are embedded devices that will not be used on a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [There isn't one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583).

Possible workarounds:

- Get a keyboard with a Windows key to use for the task.
- Use a mouse for the task.
- Recreate the master image with a desktop shortcut to a batch file that runs `explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` (more info [here](https://superuser.com/a/228909/23133) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13280/How-to-display-Windows-Explorer-objects-in-one-com)) and then deletes the shortcut, and then deletes itself (the batch file).  You can then [assign a preferred shortcut key to the shortcut](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310417) to launch it. One that doesn't depend on the <kbd>Win</kbd> key.